Total available swap memory showing as 0 bytes on macbook?
I noticed that my ram was getting full but no swap memory was being used, and it showed no swap memory available.
I ran sysctl vm.swapusage
and got this output
vm.swapusage: total = 0.00M used = 0.00M free = 0.00M (encrypted)
is there anything I need to do because this doesn't look normal
I also checked sysctl -a vm.compressor_mode
and got this
vm.compressor_mode: 4
m2pro macbook 14"

I know that it used to show 2gb total swap memory previously, unsure of what would have caused this to happen. It doesn't seem normal so what can I do to fix this?

Welcome to Ask Different. Is your Mac running any sort of workload? What level is the memory pressure? How are you measuring the memory being “full” and that there’s no swap available?

I tend to use a lot of memory for my work and I regularly see the swap being used. but I noticed my programs crashing where they normally don't and noticed that my swap memory was somehow disabled. I even checked it using fastfetch and it shows swap disabled.

My MBP M1 Pro with 32Gb RAM also shows zero swap right now and compressor mode 4; so I suspect that's more normal than you might think. (Mem Used + Cache files always equals 32Gb.) The image - what is that output from? Might you have 'customised' something that could have disabled swap? If not, it's probably fine.

The image is from fastfetch (it's like updated neofetch). I haven't customized anything as far as I know and no program I run should have the permissions to do something like that. I'm just concerned that if it is because of something I did, how do I reverse it?
